# how to add html.Validation().FormValidation() to Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

If I have this code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("CreateItem", "Item", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %> 
    <label for="ItemImage">Item Image:</label>
    Please use JPEG file format only.<br />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("ItemImage", "*") %>
<% } %>
```

And I want to use MvcContrib to catch bug, how do I add `html.validation` on `html.beginform`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "NerdDinner" sample application.  They do validation in there.

If you can't find it then add a comment to this answer and I'll provide code.